# yeoman sub-generator testing with composeWith

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman-generator, yo

I have a generator-generator app with its own local sub-generator app. The situation is that I want the sub-generator to invoke atleast once with pre-defined argument when I run the main 'app' generator. Everything works fine except the npm test fails.

Main 'app' generator: yo mygen.
Sub generator: yo mygen:foo "lorem ipsum".

Here is the test.js

```
/*global describe, beforeEach, it*/
'use strict';

var path = require('path'),
yg = require('yeoman-generator');
var helpers = require('yeoman-generator').test;
var assert = require('yeoman-assert');

describe(' running `yo mygen`', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    var deps = [
      [helpers.createDummyGenerator(), 'mygen:foo', 'blah blah blah']
    ];

    helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../app'))
      .inDir(path.join(__dirname, './temp'))  // Clear the directory and set it as the CWD
      .withOptions({ mongoose: 'app', 'skip-install': true })            // Mock options passed in
      .withPrompts({
        'dbName': 'demo',
        'useUserAuth': false
      })
      .withGenerators(deps)
      .on('end', done);
    //done();
  });

  it('can be imported without blowing up', function () {
    var app = require('../app');
    assert(app !== undefined);
  });

  it('creates all required MVC files', function (done) {
    var expected = [
      // add files you expect to exist here.
      'package.json',
      'app.js',
      'bower.json',
      'routes/index.js',
      'public/css/style.css',
      'public/js/script.js',
      'views/index.html',
      'README.md',
      '.editorconfig',
      '.jshintrc'
    ];

    assert.file(expected);
    done();
  });
});

describe('í ¼ running `yo mygen:foo`', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../schema'))
      .inDir(path.join(__dirname, './temp'))  // Clear the directory and set it as the CWD
      .withOptions({ mongoose: 'schema' })            // Mock options passed in
      .withArguments(['ha ha ha ha hha'])
      .on('end', done);
    //done();
  });

  describe('foo generator', function () {
    it('foo can be imported without blowing up', function () {
      var app = require('../foo');
      assert(app !== undefined);
    });

    it('created new MVC files for foo', function (done) {
      var expected = [
        // add files you expect to exist here.
        'view/t1.js',
        'models/t1.js',
        'controller/t1.js'
      ];
      assert.file(expected);
      done();
    })
  });
});
```

And in app/index.js, in order to invoke the sub-generator, i have used:

```
mygenGenerator.prototype.install = function install(){
  this.installDependencies();
  this.composeWith("mygen:foo", {args: ["humpty dumpty saton a wall"]});
};
```

Searched all possible answers on stackoverflow and everywhere else. Can't figure out what to do.

Test Cases for npm test fails:

1. Remove the composeWith line from index.js and the test passes.
2. keep the composeWith line, the test goes to infinity, eventually exceed 2000ms quota and failing.

Comment: Do you have an infinite loop? (subgenerator composing with the app generator?)

Comment: yes. its goes on. and hence it gives the 2000ms exceed warning.

Comment: Well then that's your issue. You cannot create infinite loop in programs or they'll just crash.

Comment: Hi, I did not intend to have an infinite loop. It just that it happens automatically. 
And for others who are facing the same problem, for the time being, I have moved the composeWith statement inside an 'if' decision whose value will be set during the starting interaction phase. This solved my problems. My test file is testing both the main **app** generator and the sub-generator one by one now.